# How to define one variable using another one in c?

Tags: c, variable-declaration

How to define a variable using another variable.Actually I want a whole string but that string should contain data from another variable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
char *Data1 = "23";
char *Data2 = "267";
char *Data = ("www.mywebsite.com?c=%s&v=%s", Data1, Data2);

int main() {
  printf(Data);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please read the manual pages. Please read about the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define an array and make use of [`sprintf()`/`snprintf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf) to generate the final string.

Something like

```
char final[128] = {0};   //128 is arbitrary value

int data1 = 23;    //no need to be string for integer value
int data2 = 267;

snprintf(final, 128, "www.mywebsite.com?c=%d&v=%d", data1, data2);
```

That said, `printf(Data);` is very invalid. You either

- use the proper format specifier, like `printf("%s", final);`
- use `puts(final);`

Comment: how do i store the output of statment `snprintf(final, 128, "www.mywebsite.com?c=%d&v=%d", data1, data2); ` in one variable.I want output as a whole string.

Comment: @bhagyakathole Did you read the linked manual page? It is stored _into_ `final`.

Comment: Is there any another solution for this statement `snprintf(final, 128, "www.mywebsite.com?c=%d&v=%d", data1, data2);`?my compiler is showing an error for this statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `snprintf`

First define a MAX_LEN and a buffer

```
#define MAX_LEN 1000
char Data[MAX_LEN + 1] = "";
```

then use `snprintf` to fill in all strings:

```
snprintf( Data, sizeof(Data), "www.mywebsite.com?c=%s&v=%s", Data1, Data2);
```

Comment: 1) why `MAX_LEN+1` ? 2) you missed passing the size.

Comment: @SouravGhosh about 1) it's called LEN, and so the size is +1

Comment: Sorry, but I still did not get. `sprintf()` writes __at most `n`__ so why the extra byte needed?

Comment: @SouravGhosh is right: "The  functions  snprintf()  and  vsnprintf()  write  at most size bytes (including the terminating null byte ('\0')) to str."

Comment: it's just how I call the name of the constant - nothing to do with the `snprintf`,  usually MAX_LEN (strlen) doesn't include the NUL character, whereas MAX_SIZE (sizeof) does.